# VB.NET How to pass an enum in a constructor

Tags: vb.net

Seems like it would be a question that I would easily find an answer to but I don't seem to be able to...

**I want to pass an enum to a constructor.**

Here is my idea:

```
Public Enum FieldEnum1
  id
  name
End Enum

Public Enum FieldEnum2
  id
  firstname
  lastname
End Enum


Private _enum as Enum
Public sub New(x as Enum)
   _enum = x
End Sub
```

where I could call New with either FieldEnum1 or FieldEnum2.

Is that doable?

TIA

Comment: **Hint:** Class vs Enum

Comment: Nobody is stopping you :) You can compare the enumerators, using the `Equals()` method. E,g. `dim myEnum as FieldEnum1 = FieldEnum1.id dim anInstance = new MyClass(myEnum)` and in MyClass you can have `private mySpecificEnum as FieldEnum2`, in sub new() you can set `mySpecificEnum = FieldEnum2.id  _enum = x dim isEqual = mySpecificEnum.Equals(_enum)`, then `isEqual` will be `false`, event though the enumerators have the same *value* (`0`, `id`), since the enumerators are different. Different story is what you'll be using these things for. Enumerators, usually, have a specific *destination*.

Comment: No it is not possible. You have to specify a single type for that field and parameter and the only type that can store values of both those `Enums` is `Object`, which covers everything else too. You could write two constructors, each with a different parameter type, but that doesn;t help you with the field.

Comment: Are you sure you want to define Enums and not classes with properties? It looks like you're on your way to writing messy hard-to-read code to be honest. It might be work re-thinking how you want to accomplish your objective.